# "Headers already sent" when file reaches certain size

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have inherited a project in Codeigniter that utilizes a custom 404 page. This page was displaying the "Headers already sent" PHP warning. I've dug for hours and finally found the cause of the error - the size of the file (specifically anything over 4.095kb).

Does anyone know why this error might be tied to the file size? I reverted to the original CI 404 page, added a bunch of code to the bottom of that file, and got the same error at the same file size.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your page is using the `ob_start()` workaround then. And the buffer overruns at typically 4K. Sending the `header()` then will therefore fail.

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of error or warning being echoed at a certain file size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the output buffering setting from php.ini (if nothing changed on runtime), see here:
http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering

It's value is 4096

You could do this on your start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php
See example #1 on that site